# Why is there no final approach fix symbol on some of the Jeppesen VOR charts? (Maltese Cross Symbol)

Tags: ils, vor, non-precision-approach, jeppesen, precision-approach

Why is there no final approach fix symbol on some of the Jeppesen VOR charts? (Maltese Cross Symbol) What does the box marked with a red arrow mean when there is no FAF symbol and how is it defined? Because sometimes it happens that "no FAF" is written in the box. If it doesn't say "no FAF" it means there is FAF but why is the FAF symbol not shown in the profile view?

[image]
[image]